# How to display specific fields from BibTeX in ConTeXt?

Tags: bibtex, context

Assuming one provides the reference, e.g. \cite{historynow1765}, how can I get ConTeXt to display specific fields for that reference, such as the title, publish date, publish location, author's full name, etc.?

E.g., assume the BibTeX file contains this entry:

```
@misc{historynow1765,
title={The Stamp Act, 1765: A Spotlight on a Primary Source    by George III},
url={https://www.gilderlehrman.org/history-now/spotlight-primary-source/stamp-act-1765},
journal={History Now},
publisher={The Gilder Institute of American History}
}
```

Some code like this might call the title information:

```
\cite[title]{historynow1765}
```

Some code like this might call the publisher information:

```
\cite[publisher]{historynow1765}
```

How can I get this specific information about a source printed in ConTeXt, taking the data from the BibTeX file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/090903.html I came up with the following solution, which seems needlessy complicated but it works nonetheless.

The idea is to add separate `\cite` setups for each individual field using

```
\startsetups btx:[stylename]:cite:[fieldname]
\btxfield{fieldname}
\stopsetups
```

This enables the syntax `\cite[fieldname][refname]`.

The complicated part is how to convince ConTeXt to actually use these definitions. For this a new style can be created, for example named `singlefields`. This style can be based on an existing style, such as `apa`. Following the link above I did the following:

- copy `publ-imp-apa.lua` and `publ-imp-apa.mkvi` to the working directory and rename them as `publ-imp-singlefields.lua` and `publ-imp-singlefields.mkvi`. Note that this means that regular `\cite` and the reference list will be formatted in APA style.
- in `publ-imp-singlefields.mkvi` replace all occurrences of `apa` with `singlefields`
- add the `\startsetups` code (see below)
- in `publ-imp-singlefields.lua`, add the extra fields to the `misc` entry (see below)

Single field code:

```
\startsetups btx:singlefields:cite:publisher
\btxfield{publisher}
\stopsetups

\startsetups btx:singlefields:cite:journal
\btxfield{journal}
\stopsetups

\startsetups btx:singlefields:cite:title
\btxfield{title}
\stopsetups

\startsetups btx:singlefields:cite:url
\btxfield{url}
\stopsetups
```

Misc entry:

```lua
categories.misc = {
    sets = {
        doi  = generic.doi,
    },
    required = {
        -- nothing is really important here
    },
    optional = {
        "author", "withauthor", "translator",
        "title", "subtitle", "file",
        "year", "month",
        "howpublished",
        "doi", "note",
        "publisher", "journal", "url",
    },
}
```

Document:

```
\usebtxdataset[ctxfields.bib]
\usebtxdefinitions[singlefields]

\starttext

Only title: \cite[title][historynow1765]

Only journal: \cite[journal][historynow1765]

Only publisher: \cite[publisher][historynow1765]

\subject[title=\bf References]

\placelistofpublications

\stoptext
```

Result:

[image]

Remark: for some reason this also works out of the box with only adding the fields to the `.lua` file and not changing the `.mkvi` file at all, however then the journal and publisher are printed in a monospace font. Besides this, another advantage of the outlined approach is that you can also change the appearance of the bibliography entries, using the setup `\startsetups btx:[stylename]:list:[entrytype]` syntax.